# Show most recent entry in multiple lines of text unless the field is blank

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer

Is it possible to show the most recent entry in a multi-line text box with `Append changes` turned on, unless the entry is a blank?

This is an attempt at the solution, but I couldn't get it to work for me: http://sharepoint-ravi.blogspot.com/2010/11/append-changes-to-existing-text-feature.html

By using the method in this link, I was able to show the most recent entry, but if the item is edited and the multi-line text box is not updated, it shows a blank: https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/pages/taming-the-elusive-calculated-column-referencing-a-multiple-lines-of-text-column-with-append-text-part-1.aspx

I know how to make the multi-line text box show all the entries excluding blanks, but I'm curious if there's a way to show only the most recent entry excluding blanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix could be to make your multi-line field mandatory that way it cannot be left blank.

The issue you have is that the comments are stored as versions so the only option I can think of would be to use something like jQuery to loop through the versions of the multi-line field until it comes to the most recent one that is not blank.